# Layers parallax effect in GameScene.sks

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I used to build my game parallax effect by adding deferent layers to the scene and implement the mechanism in the - (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime or in - (void)didSimulatePhysics by moving the whole layer and all it’s contents according to the camera which is flowing the main player etc… (old school stuff  ) and that works fine but now I want to use the level editor in the GameScene.sks to save time for building the game levels but I have some difficulty find how to add my sprites to deferent layers and apply the parallax mechanism on those layers inside the GameScene.sks file! any help?